# onActivityResult not firing in zxing

Tags: android, zxing, onactivityresult

I'm using zxing library. I call to the library  with the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The barcode starts, and it reads the qrcode. The problem is that it never returns to my activity. This is my code for it.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

           if (requestCode == 0) {

              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                 String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                 String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                 TextView txtCambiado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                 txtCambiado.setText(contents);


          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                 // Handle cancel
          }
       }
    }
```

The app never execute onActivityResult. Zxing shows the result but it does not return to my app. 
Please, can someone help me?

---

```
my manifest file is. I think the problem has something to do with it.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.acme.prueba"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
android:protectionLevel="normal" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:configChanges="orientation"

    >

    <activity
        android:name="com.acme.prueba.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
  android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
  android:stateNotNeeded="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you calling startActivityForResult from a Fragment or an Activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Have added the intent filter in your manifest ?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: It doesn't seems related to zxing. Maybe your activity launchMode is singleInstance ?

Comment: No, in the manifest i haven't defined anything for android:launchMode

Comment: I have seen in logcat that after Zxing has read the qrcode, is shown the next error: MediaPayer "Error(-19,0)", and MediaPlayer "Should have subtittle controller already set". Can it be the cause of zxing doesn´t return to OnactivityResult?

Comment: Zxing plays a "beep" sound when you take the picture. It seems to be related to this : the sound fails, zxing crashs and you come back to your activity because of it.Could you check if you have beep.ogg in your raw folder ? If you use Zxing as a jar it should be in your res folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, now i see where can be the error. But I have just seen that the file beep.ogg exists in res/raw. What can I do?

Comment: I'm trying in Emulator Nexus One (Android 4.4.2). Has it something to do with the configuration of the emulator?

Comment: Zxing needs the camera which is incompatible with an emulator. You should try your app on a real device. Here are others ideas : launch in debug mode and see why there is an exception ; re-download the zxing jar ; laucnh the intent from an empty project ...

Comment: I have achieved that the error doesn`t appear by deleting the lines beepManager.updatePrefs(); and beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate(); but I have the same issue. Zxing shows the result but it doesn´t return to OnactivityResult. The last line in logcat is: CaptureActivityhandle: got decode succedded menssage. No errors in logcat. But what can I do to return to my activity to show there the result?

Comment: [This is project](http://sharesend.com/g4jfwiab) is working for me. If you can run it, the problem is related to your project. If you can't, the problem is related to your device/config.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I try your proyect on my emulator, it doesn´t read any code. Open the camera and shows the red line, but that's all. I don´t know if it is because of the device configurator or the zxing version.

Comment: An emulator doesn't have a camera, you can't play zxing on it.

Comment: Does it work on a real device ? Thank you to accept my answer if it is.

Comment: Against which reciever I am adding `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>` ?